# Two-dimensional smooth.spline in R

Tags: splines, smoothing

Following a suggestion of Cosma Shalizi ([https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/TALR/TALR.pdf](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Ecshalizi/TALR/TALR.pdf), page 368)
I am trying to build an iterative weighted least square fit, but for a regression with two predictors (instead of one predictor, as described).
The central idea of the method is to weigh the predictor(s) by the associated variance, which is estimated from a spline fit to the log of the squared residuals.
For one predictor, R's `smooth.spline` function is used to obtain that fit.  I have been looking for a similar R function that would work for two (or even more) dimensions, but could not find any. Any suggestion would be welcome!